# Access Google-cloud compute engine API from AWS Lambda

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, google-cloud-platform, aws-lambda

I'm trying to get data from Google cloud cloud-billing and compute-engine APIs. I am using Google`s nodejs SKD inside AWS lambda. The function run complete with wanted results in dev (using AWS toolkit for vscode). Testing the lambda, I'm getting

> "errorMessage": "RequestId: ... Error: Runtime exited with error: signal: killed"
> Which I read has to do with excessive memory use.
> In addition, when I'm trying to log the results from my api calls, I receive nothing.

My Application Default Credentials file from the service account looks like:

```
{
  "type": "service_account",
  "project_id": "",
  "private_key_id": "",
  "private_key": "",
  "client_email": "",
  "client_id": "",
  "auth_uri": "",
  "token_uri": "",
  "auth_provider_x509_cert_url": "",
  "client_x509_cert_url": "",
  "universe_domain": "googleapis.com"
}
```

and it's path is in the lambdas env.

My lambda`s partial code is:

```
const AWS = require('aws-sdk');
const { CloudCatalogClient } = require('@google-cloud/billing').v1;
const { MachineTypesClient } = require('@google-cloud/compute').v1;


const FROM_NANOS = 1000000000.0;
const FROM_GIBY = 1024;

 
async function getSkuList() {
  const billingClient = new CloudCatalogClient();

  const computeEngineServiceId = await getComputeEngineServiceId (billingClient);
  const billingRequest = {
    parent: computeEngineServiceId,
  };
  
  // https://cloud.google.com/nodejs/docs/reference/billing/latest/billing/v1.cloudcatalogclient
  const skuList = await billingClient.listSkusAsync(billingRequest); 
  console.dir("skuList: ", skuList) // shows only text in lambdas logs

  // billingClient.close();
  return [ skuList, billingClient ];
}


// Get Compute-Engine service id
async function getComputeEngineServiceId (billingClient) {
  let computeEngine = null;
  let pageToken = null;
  
  do {
    const serviceList = await billingClient.listServicesAsync({ pageToken });
    pageToken = serviceList.nextPageToken;
      
    for await (const service of serviceList) {
      if (service.displayName === "Compute Engine") {
        computeEngine = service.name;
        break;
      }
    }
  } while (!computeEngine && pageToken)

  if (!computeEngine) {
    throw new Error("Compute engine service not found");
  }

  return computeEngine;  
}


// Get instances list for zone us-east1-a
async function getInstancesTypes() {  
  const instancesClient = new MachineTypesClient();
  const instancesRequest = {
    project: process.env.projectId,
    zone: "us-east1-a",
  };
  
  const res = [];

  const instances = await instancesClient.listAsync(instancesRequest);

  console.dir("instances: ", instances) // shows only text in lambdas logs

  for await (const type of instances) {
    const instance = {
      instanceType: type.name,
      memorySize: type.memoryMb,
      cpuCount: type.guestCpus,
    }
    
    res.push(instance);
  }

  instancesClient.close();
  return res;
}

// LAMBDA HANDLER
exports.handler = async function(event, context, callback) {
  try {
    ... 
   
    const [skuList, billingClient ] = await getSkuList();
    const instancesTypes = await getInstancesTypes();
    
    for await (const sku of skuList) {
      ...
    }

    billingClient.close()
  
    
      
    const resultV1 = {
      timestamp: Date.now(),
      cloudProvider: 'GCP',
      ...
    };
    
    console.log(" : ", JSON.stringify(resultV1));

  

    callback(null, "Success");
  } catch (error) {
    console.error(error.message);
    throw error;
  }
};
```

Any Idea what can I do in order to make things work?
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error message `Runtime exited with error: signal: killed` typically occurs when an AWS Lambda function exceeds its allocated resources or execution time limit.

The Google Cloud Compute Engine API may require significant resources or time to complete certain operations, and AWS Lambda has some limitations that can cause this error.

AWS Lambda allows you to configure the amount of memory allocated to a function. Try increasing the allocated memory to provide more resources for the function to execute. Higher memory allocation also increases the CPU power available to the function.
If your function performs CPU-intensive tasks, consider adjusting the timeout configuration as well. Longer timeouts may be required for tasks that take more time to complete.

If the issue persists it would be best to reach out to AWS support for further assistance.

Comment: Thanks! I had to quadruplet the memory and the timeout values, but it worked!